# How to merge 3 Sheets from different Excel files into one sheet with C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, spire.xls

Here I tried to merge two excel files into one excel sheet using below mentioned code (Spire.Xls dll)  its working fine.

Here is code for two excel merging.

```
 workbook = new Workbook();
 //load the first workbook
 workbook.LoadFromFile(ArrayExcelFiles[0]);
 //load the second workbook
 Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
 workbook2.LoadFromFile(ArrayExcelFiles[1]);
 //import the second workbook's worksheet into the first workbook using a datatable
 Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];
 DataTable dataTable = sheet2.ExportDataTable();
 Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[0];
 sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);

 workbook.SaveToFile(OutputPath + "Merged.xls", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
```

But the problem is that when am trying to merge three excel files using same logic the output was same as two merged excel output third excel is not merged.

Here is the code for three excel files.

```
Workbook workbook1 = new Workbook();
//load the first workbook
workbook1.LoadFromFile(ArrayExcelFiles[0]);
//load the second workbook
Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
workbook2.LoadFromFile(ArrayExcelFiles[1]);
//load the third workbook
Workbook workbook3 = new Workbook();
workbook3.LoadFromFile(ArrayExcelFiles[2]);

//import the second workbook's worksheet into the first workbook using a datatable
Worksheet sheet3 = workbook3.Worksheets[0];
DataTable dataTable = sheet3.ExportDataTable();
Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];
dataTable = sheet2.ExportDataTable();
Worksheet sheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets[0];
sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);
workbook1.SaveToFile(OutputPath + "Merged.xls", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
```

Comment: You are *not* merging the third file. You are not  exporting the data from it into a DataTable and *not* inserting it into the target.

Comment: I'd suggest you try to understand what the code does before trying to modify it. Then try to *clean* it - if you need to merge two or more sheets into one why not turn that into a loop?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thank you sir for quick response. But the same logic is applied there for two excel merging code mentioned above. Am not exporting the second file (i.e sheet1) into DataTable but its working fine.

Comment: @vinodkarampuri the problem though is that you haven't applied the logic correctly in the code...see my answer (or the other one, for that matter). It's one thing to know the logic, and another thing to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the same logic in the second example, thus it does not work. Try something like this on the second code or change it a bit:

```
//import the second workbook's worksheet into the first workbook using a datatable
Worksheet sheet3 = workbook3.Worksheets[0];

Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];
DataTable dataTable2 = sheet2.ExportDataTable();

Worksheet sheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets[0];
DataTable dataTable1 = sheet1.ExportDataTable();

sheet3.InsertDataTable(dataTable2, false, sheet3.LastRow + 1, 1)
sheet3.InsertDataTable(dataTable1, false, sheet3.LastRow + 1, 1)
```

The code above takes `sheet3` and inserts 2 data tables to it -  one from `sheet2` and one from `sheet1`.

Answer (score 1):

You only ever insert the sheet from `workbook2`, so it's not surprising. You got `datatable` from `workbook3`, but then immediately over-wrote it with data from `workbook2`, before you did anything else with it. You can't store two tables in one `DataTable` object. The last one simply replaces the first one (just like any other variable assignment).

You need to run two separate `insertDataTable` commands with two separate data tables, one from each sheet:

```
//import the second and third workbooks' worksheets into the first workbook using a datatable
Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];
DataTable dataTable = sheet2.ExportDataTable();

Worksheet sheet3 = workbook3.Worksheets[0];
DataTable dataTable2 = sheet3.ExportDataTable();

Worksheet sheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets[0];
sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);
sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable2, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);
workbook1.SaveToFile(OutputPath + "Merged.xls", ExcelVersion.Version2007);
```

Of course the code could be made a lot neater and less repetitive by using loops etc, but this is the basic solution.