# Is it possible to append multiple .xls files into a single Excel 2003 worksheet without Office Interop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, merge, excel-2003

I have an ASP.NET Web API and need to implement this feature for a future version. Specifically:

- Several .xls files will be placed in a temporary folder. They have the same width but different heights, as well as different row and column sizes.
- The files need to be appended into one .xls file
- The final excel cannot have multiple worksheets.
- The Office Interop libraries cannot be used because Office is not installed and cannot be instaled on the deployment environment.

Is there a way to do this without using the office interop libraries as specified, or any paid third party libraries (free third party libraries are more than welcome) ?

Comment: I don't have time to explain everything right now sadly but look up OpenXml-SDK and the corresponding powertools by Eric White. It works without office installed but is a bit tricky to get into.

Comment: OpenXML isn't going to work with .XLS (only .XLSX). If your stuck with the former try NPOI https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi

Comment: I see, I'll take a lok at NPOI. Thanks for your replies :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Spire.XLS from [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spire.XLS/): **Install-Package Spire.XLS -Version 9.6.7**

Spire.XLS provides two ways to merge excel files into a single excel worksheet:

**1. Merge excel with styles using CellRange.Copy()**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string outputPath = "‪output.xls";
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    files.Add(@"File1.xls");
    files.Add(@"File2.xls");
    CombineFiles(files, outputPath);
}
private static void CombineFiles(List<string> files, string outputPath)
{
    Spire.Xls.Workbook resultworkbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
    resultworkbook.Worksheets.Clear();
    Spire.Xls.Worksheet resultworksheet = resultworkbook.Worksheets.Add("worksheet");

    Spire.Xls.Workbook workbook = new Spire.Xls.Workbook();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        workbook.LoadFromFile(files[i]);
        Worksheet sheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];
        if (i == 0)
        {
            sheet.AllocatedRange.Copy(resultworksheet.Range[1, 1], true, true);

        }
        else
        {
            sheet.AllocatedRange.Copy(resultworksheet.Range[resultworksheet.LastRow + 1, 1], true, true);
        }
    }


    resultworkbook.SaveToFile(outputPath, ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
}
```

Reference: [How to merge multiple worksheets to a single worksheet with styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53172931/how-to-merge-multiple-worksheets-to-a-single-worksheet-with-styles)

**2. Merge excel without styles using DataTable**

```
Workbook workbook1 = new Workbook();
//load the first workbook
workbook1.LoadFromFile(FilePath1);
//load the second workbook
Workbook workbook2 = new Workbook();
workbook2.LoadFromFile(FilePath2);
//load the third workbook
Workbook workbook3 = new Workbook();
workbook3.LoadFromFile(FilePath3);

//import the second and third workbook's first worksheet into the first workbook using datatable
Worksheet sheet1 = workbook1.Worksheets[0];
Worksheet sheet2 = workbook2.Worksheets[0];
Worksheet sheet3 = workbook3.Worksheets[0];

DataTable dataTable1 = sheet2.ExportDataTable();
DataTable dataTable2 = sheet3.ExportDataTable();

sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable1, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);
sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable2, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);

workbook1.SaveToFile(OutputPath + "Merged.xls", ExcelVersion.Version97to2003);
```

Reference: [How to merge 3 Sheets from different Excel files into one sheet with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51653543/how-to-merge-3-sheets-from-different-excel-files-into-one-sheet-with-c-sharp/51653707#51653707)

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply. I looked into spire and while it doesn't copy the atypical row and column sizes properly it allows for easy conversion to xlsx, which in turn opens up a lot of possibilities with other third party libraries.